# Jquery with html and css

Tags: jquery

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#" class="navigation-bar-toggle">
                <i class="ion-navicon-round"></i>Menu </a>

            <div class="navigation-bar-wrapper">
```

when tag is clicked extra class active should be added to  tag and the next div tags class navigation bar wrapper

Comment: "Hi" <-- Great way to start a message, isn't it ? :) What's your question here ? And what did you already try ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$('.navigation-bar-toggle').click(function(){
   $('.navigation-bar-toggle, .navigation-bar-wrapper').removeClass('active');
   $(this).add($(this).next('.navigation-bar-wrapper')).addClass('active');
});
```

See [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass) , [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass) , [next](http://api.jquery.com/next)  and [add](http://api.jquery.com/add) methods.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : Register a click handler for `<a>` tag and add `active` class using `addClass()`. Also remove previously added `active` class if it is required for you.

```
$(function(){
  $('.navigation-bar-toggle').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       //to remove prevously added active class use below line
       $('.active').removeClass('active');

       $(this).addClass('active');
       $(this).next('div.navigation-bar-wrapper').addClass('active');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a click handler like

```
//dom ready handler
jQuery(function ($) {
    //click handler for the `a` elements
    var $navas = $('#site-navigation .navigation-bar-toggle').click(function () {
        //remove active class from previously selected item
        $navas.filter('.active').not(this).next().addBack().removeClass('active');

        $(this).next('.navigation-bar-wrapper').addBack().toggleClass('active');
    })
})
```